# Facebook: $facebook->getSession(); return null

Tags: php, facebook

HI,

I am new to FB development and just starting developing the app for blood donors site.

I have used the sample code provided on developers section, it worked and I started building. Later in the middle I decided to check the initial starting process again and created a dummy account which is totally fresh. Note: The new account have never added the app, its just the landing page issue.

Below Are the different results, just ran the print_r() on $session.

Ubuntu 10.04 FF 3.6.14: `complete array of session.`

Ubuntu 10.04 Chromium 9.0.597.107:`null`

Ubuntu Virtual Box, IE8: `Null`

Windows 7 FF Beta: `null`

I am not sure why there are different behaviors. Also I have tested windows 7 with an old account and it showed `NULL`

Comment: did you log in for the rest of the other browser?

Comment: require 'facebook.php'; $facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => '116147391794481', 'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'cookie' => true, )); $session = $facebook->getSession(); print_r($session); any how I am just checking if $me exists. If not then I show ADD APPLICATION button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$facebook->getSession()` returns false, try redirecting the user to `$fb->getLoginUrl()` and get a new session. The browser shouldn't matter, only that you might have your Facebook cookies cached on FF3.6.

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!$session)
{
    header("Location: ".$facebook->getLoginUrl());
    exit;
}
else
{
    // do stuff
}
```